# What is rescache.hit?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi, windows-mui

I am having some issues with my c++ application - Symantec Critical System Protection blocks my application because it tries to access `C:\Windows\rescache\rcXXXX\ResCache.hit`.

From googling I managed to find out that it is related to MUI, but nothing specific.

Also I enabled auditing for those files in `rescache` and tried to replicate this in my dev environment. However, I never seen any attempts from my application to access `ResCache.hit`, it was always accessed only by svchost.exe.

So what is ResCache.hit and how it can be modified from your application (e.g. if there any WINAPI calls that can result into your application accessing that file or something like that)?